# Managing size of partition while installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

My laptop's hard disk is 1 TB and total memory is 8 GB, it has two partition. One is for C drive where windows installed and other is for Ubuntu installation ; size 512 GB

While installing Ubuntu, what type of partition should I create?

Should I create swap or not? If yes.. How much size should I allocate? ( total memory 8 GB)

Creating a root partition, How much size should I allocate? 
Help me to manage! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Creating Swap can be helpful at times, but since your memory is already high, no necessity. However,  it is a good practice to create swap partitions.

This is a guide to create partitions:

1. You can choose to Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager, an option that will automatically take care of all the partition steps.

   Use this option if you don’t require a personalized partition scheme. In case you want a custom partition layout, check the Something else option and hit on the Continue button to proceed further.

   The option "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" should be avoided on dual-boot because is potentially dangerous and will wipe out your disk.

   [image]
2. On this step, we’ll create our custom partition layout for Ubuntu 16.04. This guide will recommend that you create two partitions, one for root and the other for home accounts data and no partition for swap (use a swap partition only if you have limited RAM resources or you use a fast SSD).

   To create the first partition, the root partition, select the free space (the shrinking space from Windows created earlier) and hit on the + icon below. On partition settings use the following configurations and hit OK to apply changes:

   - Size = at least  20 GB, 50 GB would be ideal
   - Type for the new partition = Primary
   - Location for the new partition = Beginning
   - Use as = EXT4 journaling file system
   - Mount point = `/`

   [image]

   [image]
3. Use 16 GB for the swap partition size. Click on unallocated space, click on new. Enter the size as 16GB, choose primary partition, file system type SWAP.
4. Use all the available free space left for the home partition size. The partition settings should look like this:

   - Size = all remaining free space
   - Type for the new partition = Primary
   - Location for the new partition = Beginning
   - Use as = EXT4 journaling file system
   - Mount point = `/home`

   [image]
5. When finished, hit the Install Now button in order to apply changes to disk and start the installation process.

   A pop-up window should appear to inform you about swap space. Ignore the alert by pressing on the Continue button.

   Next, a new pop-up window will ask you if you agree with committing changes to disk. Hit Continue to write changes to disk and the installation process will now start.

For the complete installation procedure, refer to https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/#

Comment: The pictures have been taken off the web and hence may be in contrast to the values given in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install gparted on livecd for more convenience to manage partitions

```
sudo install gparted
```

Swap partitions are not necessary if you already have enough rams to run your programs, but a swap partition larger than your ram is needed if you want to enable hibernation.

In some cases, swap partitions will allow your run programs to consume more memory than you have, but it also badly slow down your system and make it seems `frozen'.